# Most probable path for stochastic Hamiltonian systems

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, hamiltonian-mechanics, large-deviations

It is known that for a real valued stochastic process $X_t$ satisfying 
$$
d X_t = b(X_t) d  t + \sigma d W_t 
$$
where $W$ is real valued Wiener process, the equation for the most probable path from a state $x$ at time $t$ to another state $y$ at time $T$, is of the form
$$
\ddot x = b(x)b'(x)+ \frac{\sigma^2}{2}b''(x) 
$$
with
$$
x(t) = x, \quad x(T) = y.
$$ 
For instance, when $\sigma = 1$ and $b \equiv 0$, the most probable path connecting $x$ to $y$ between the instants $t$ and $T$ is 
$$
w(s) = \frac{1}{2}(x+y) + \frac{y-x}{T-t} \left ( s - \frac{T+t}{2}\right )
$$
(Not too bad for a process that is nowhere differentiable.)

Is there any reference concerning the equation for the most probable path for second order SDEs of the form
$$
d X_t = F(X_t,Y_t) d t,
\quad
d Y_t = G(X_t,Y_t) d t + \sigma d W_t
$$
I have in mind stochastic Hamiltonian systems in the sense of Talay, [Stochastic Hamiltonian dissipative systems: exponential convergence to the invariant measure, and discretization by the implicit Euler scheme. Markov Processes and Related Fields 8(2), 163-198, 2002.]

Comment: What is your definition of most probable path? Is it minimizer of Onsager-Machlup functional?

Comment: yes, in the sense of equation (8,5) page 169 of [The Onsager-Machlup Function as Lagrangian for the Most Probable Path of a Diffusion Process, Detlef Dύrr and Alexander Bach, Commun. math. Phys. 60, 153—170 (1978) ].

Comment: My question was about the definition of "most probable", not about the solution (which is the equation you cite). More specifically, are you measuring only the displacement of Y from a path phi or both X and Y? This issue always arises in the non uniformly elliptic case.

Comment: More specifically, for nice diffusions $x_t$ the OM functional is $\lim _{\epsilon \to 0} P(\|x-\phi\|<\epsilon)/P(\|x\|<\epsilon)$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is carefully chosen. What is $\| \cdot \|$ in your question?